# Замена символов в div'е картинкой

Tags: jquery-ui

Здравствуйте, подскажите как можно реализовать вот такое! Если пользователь в блок с текстом вставил комбинацию символов ;) например то это заменилось картинкой(смайликом).Желательно это сделать на jquery тк сообщения будут постоянно подгружаться. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример кода для замены символов: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n5VU/3/).

```
var text = 'hi all! :)';

function replaceEmotion (text) {
    var newText = text.replace(/:\)/g, '<img width="23" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCp1ny3sdYH4gFBlHFLEpvJcIiMq1VtZE1SiAjoe8B4AoPqbXd">');
    return newText;
}

document.body.innerHTML = replaceEmotion(text);
```

Суть в том, что бы брать каждое сообщение и искать в нем нужное сочетании символов, заменяя его на тег картинки (например).

Этот код можно расширить, создав массив сочетаний символов и их замены.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше отправлять сообщение на сервер с помощью ajax и на стороне сервера его обрабатывать. В целом не понятно, что вы хотите получить.